# How to copy categories from one root category to another?

Tags: magento, categories

I have created multiple website as **website1** and **website2** in magento enterprise edition 1.11.2. 
I want to copy all the categories from **website1** to **website2**. How can I do it?
Now I am doing it manually. if anybody knows how to do it with code.

Please provide guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different websites can share the same root catalog. You can set the root catalog for the store(s) of each site  at `system -> manage stores`.

Comment: thanks but I want to use two different root categories because I have some changes in category desciption